# SVN permissions editor

Tags: permissions, svn

As far as I know all SVN path-based permissions have to be manually entered in a text file.

Does anyone know if there is a nice editor for SVN path-based permissions?
By "nice" I mean UI appealing and good usability.

My scenario is: I have got a hosted SVN server on a Linux machine (FTP, SFTP and SSH access) and I want to manage the per path permissions from a GUI-windows-based-editor (my PC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very nice tool called suafe which is a free subversion user authorization file editor. I am using the same and is very light weight and comfortable. 
you can get it from: http://code.google.com/p/suafe/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). [VisualSVN Server Manager](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/#console) console features a very nice GUI to manage path-based authorization settings. You don't need to edit `authz` file manually, everything can be done through the management console.

[image: VisualSVN Server Manager security settings]

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I may have expressed myself wrongly.

My scenario is: I have got a hosted SVN server on a Linux machine (FTP, SFTP and SSH access) and I want to manage the per path permissions from a GUI-windows-based-editor (my PC).

Do you see that possible with any kind of tool?

Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know any GUI for SVN path-based authorization, except VisualSVN Server's. The tool @vivec mentioned *may* help you however I've never tried it. Installing Java just for one minor tool is an overkill, I 'spose.